# Facebook app on localhost: I'm getting different user id

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have a website running on my localhost and I want to test the Facebook integration. 
I have created 2 Facebook apps, one for the live site, the other one for the localhost site.

They works both, but when I login to the local app, my returned user id is 
10204483432301440

When I login to the live app, my returned user id is 
1101244663

The weird thing is that both ids brings me to my facebook page:
https://www.facebook.com/10204483432301440 --> sends me to https://www.facebook.com/francesco.eandi
https://www.facebook.com/1101244663 --> sends me to https://www.facebook.com/francesco.eandi as well!

Is it right? So do we have on facebook different user ids?

Comment: FOR ANDROID

If you need to change the APP_ID and the APP_NAME you can go into the file named "facebookconnect.xml" in platforms -> res -> values and find the resources named fb_app_id and fb_app_name. Remove those.

After you have done that, find the file named android.json in platforms -> android.json

edit the values under "res/values/facebookconnect.xml" to the new app_id and app_name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> App-scoped User IDs: To better protect people's information, when people log into a version of your app that has been upgraded to use Graph API v2.0, Facebook will now issue an app-scoped ID rather than that person's orginal ID. However, for users that have previously logged into your app, the user ID will not change.

Btw, if you need to map user IDs between Apps, this may help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Although i would not use this for dev/live. you can use "Test Apps" for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps